# Fetching the server IP from URL

Tags: javascript, php, url, dns, ip

Suppose I go on to some website from my chrome browser. Is it possible in any programing language like PHP, js to fetch the server IP of a webpage from its URL.
(for eg: like we do using NSlookup). 
Is it possible to write a script to get the server IP of a webpage using its URL.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
<?php
$domain = "www.google.com";

$ip = gethostbyname($domain);

echo "Domain: ".$domain;
echo "<br>";
echo "IP: ".$ip;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
echo $hostname;
```